# cypress test sometimes runs indefinitely

Tags: cypress

Sometimes, for whatever reason, one of the tests in cypress will get stuck and continue to run indefinitely until I manually stop the test suite. It completely ignores any timeouts already set up in cypress.
What is the best way to safeguard and automatically fail just that one test -- without halting the entire test suite?

Comment: Is this behaviour on UI run or headless?

Comment: Does it get stuck on a specific command each time, or is it random?

Comment: UI so far, although we mostly run our tests with the UI so I can't guarantee it wouldnt happen headless @PrzemyslawJanBeigert

Comment: I'll have to pay more attention to see if there is a pattern @JordanKowal , but what I'm looking for is a general catch all regardless of where the test gets stuck